# Inline CSS editing and Live Preview

Tags: css

I am **NOT** after anyone to code this, I am after some advice and possibly links to similar system, that we may learn from

I have searched long and hard, but had no luck. What I am wanting to do is:

Have a webpage with two panes. Demo image below.

[image]

Upper Pane: holds a CSS file, like a textarea. User can edit and save as they go. With a Preview button below..
..which onclick shows a preview pane or modal window. With the css changes to a particular file.

I suppose its a bit like JS fiddle, but it preloads a specific css file.
The Preview pane has a specific html file loaded. So that when user saves the session updates the css file, and they can se their progress.

I know this isnt a question in the strictest sense, and perhaps before voting down you may just assist with some pointers to similar scripts .. or logic. As it is I have had no luck finding anything that can do this, let alone knowing where to start to create something like this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net isn't too far off this "vision", so I would say maybe start with the same fiddle (URL) and go from there?

Comment: Hi Jared, yuup I agree. My particular scenario is to create something we can deploy on our own website.

Comment: SO is not a solution market, so I believe your original concept of the viability of this approach is probably correct.

Comment: Yup, I reckon you hit the nail on the head. Why reinvent the wheel. Cheers Jared ( marked up )

Answer (score 0):

Another one pure css *jsfiddle* [Dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/):

Instant preview, increment/decrement by alt+up/down keys

[image]